# perl code execution order

Tags: linux, perl

The below is driving me crazy.

I submit the whole function for clarity. The aim here is to log an error every time a Linux mirror sub-device is faulty OR when a sub-device has been removed. I just need to have one message every time. mdadm commands output always displays a line with removed and a line with faulty if the sub-device has not been completely removed from the mirror and is in faulted state. I just want to log only the sub-device faulty part in this case and not the removed one.

One the device has been removed from the mirror, there is no faulty error any more, but only removed. In this case I need to log the removed error.

For that I use a variable `$myfaulty` and parse the `mdadm --detail $md_dev` output.
The problem is that the part of the code that comes first is evaluated second.

**The below code comes first:**

```
elsif ($subdevice_status =~ /faulty/) {
_msg("ERROR: MD device $device status $device_status, sub-device status $subdevice_status " );
_mylog('err', "ERROR: faulty MD $device $device_status: sub-device $subdevice ($subdevice_role): status $subdevice_status " );
  $myfaulty = 1;
```

**And this comes second:**

```
elsif ($subdevice_status =~ /removed/ && $myfaulty != 1 ) {
 _msg("ERROR: MD device $device status $device_status, sub-device status $subdevice_status " );
 printf("The removed part: $myfaulty, $device, $raid_type \n");
 _mylog('err', "ERROR: MD device $device status $device_status, sub-device $subdevice_status " );
```

The $myfaulty variable evaluation happens first on the second block of code and then on the first.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
George

### Sub code

```
# checks all MD volumes it finds on the system
sub check_md() {
my $MDADMCMD = "";
my $device = "";
my $subdevice = "";
my $device_status = "";
my $subdevice_status = "";
my $raid_type = "";
my $subdevice_role = "";
my $raid_count = 0;
my $lines = 0;
my $myfaulty = 0;

    foreach(@mdadm_paths) {
            if( -e $_ ) { $MDADMCMD = $_; _debug("using mdadm in $MDADMCMD"); last; }
    }
    if($MDADMCMD eq "") { _msg("MD not configured on this system (mdadm not found) - "); return; }
    open MDSCAN, "-|", "$MDADMCMD --detail --scan --verbose 2>&1" || die "can't run: $!";
    while(<MDSCAN>) {
            $lines++;
            if($_ =~ /^ARRAY/) {
                    $_ =~ /^ARRAY\s+(\S+)\s+level=(\S+)\s+/;
                    $device = $1;
                    $raid_type = $2;
                    $raid_count++;
                    _debug("found MD device $device, raid-level $raid_type");
            open MDDETAIL, "-|", "$MDADMCMD --detail $device" || die "can't run: $!"; while(<MDDETAIL>) {
    printf($_);
                            if($_ =~ /\s+State\s+:\s+(.+)$/) { # md device status
                                    $device_status = $1;
                                    chomp($device_status);
                                    _debug("device status: $device_status");


                                    if($device_status !~ /clean$/) {
                                            change_status("CRITICAL");
                                            $md_status = "CRITICAL";

                            }

                             if($_ =~ /^\s+(\d+|-)\s+(\d+|-)\s+(\d+|-)\s+(\d+|-)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\S+)\s*$/) {
                                    $subdevice_status = $5; $subdevice_role = $6; $subdevice = $7;
                                    _debug("device:$device - subdevice:$subdevice - role:$subdevice_role - status:$subdevice_status");
                                    if($subdevice_status !~ /active/) {
                                            change_status("CRITICAL");
                                            $md_status = "CRITICAL";
                                            _msg("MD $device, sub-device $subdevice ($subdevice_role): status $subdevice_status - ");
                                            if ($subdevice_role =~ /rebuilding/) {
                                            _mylog('warning', "WARNING: MD $device $device_status: sub-device $subdevice ($subdevice_role): status $subdevice_status " );
                                             }
                                            elsif ($subdevice_status =~ /faulty/) {
                                            _msg("ERROR: MD device $device status $device_status, sub-device status $subdevice_status " );
                                            _mylog('err', "ERROR: faulty MD $device $device_status: sub-device $subdevice ($subdevice_role): status $subdevice_status " );
                                            $myfaulty = 1;
                                            printf("Faulty is here:  $myfaulty, $subdevice_status, $raid_type \n");
                                            }
                                            elsif ($subdevice_status =~ /removed/ && $myfaulty != 1 ) {
                                                     _msg("ERROR: MD device $device status $device_status, sub-device status $subdevice_status " );
                                                     printf("The removed part: $myfaulty, $device, $raid_type \n");
                                                     _mylog('err', "ERROR: MD device $device status $device_status, sub-device $subdevice_status " );

                                            }
                                            else {
                                            _msg("MD $device, sub-device $subdevice ($subdevice_role): status $subdevice_status - ");
                                            _mylog('err', "ERROR: after faulty MD $device $device_status: sub-device $subdevice ($subdevice_role): status $subdevice_status " );
                                            }
                                    }
                                            else { _verbosemsg("MD $device, sub-device $subdevice ($subdevice_role): status OK - "); }
                             # Need to also catch subdevices that have been removed and don't show up anymore.
                    }
                    if ($_ =~ /^\s+(\d+|-)\s+(\d+|-)\s+(\d+|-)\s+(\d+|-)\s+(\w+)\s*$/) {
                                   $subdevice_status = $5;
                                     _debug("device:$device - subdevice:$subdevice - role:$subdevice_role - status:$subdevice_status");

                                            printf("The removed part: $myfaulty, $device, $raid_type \n");
                                    if ($subdevice_status =~ m/removed/ && $myfaulty != 1 ) {
                                            _msg("ERROR: MD device $device status $device_status, sub-device status $subdevice_status " );
                                            printf("The removed part: $myfaulty, $device, $raid_type \n");
                                            _mylog('err', "ERROR: MD device $device status $device_status, sub-device $subdevice_status " );
                                            }
                            }
                    } #while(<MDDETAIL>)
                    close(MDDETAIL);
            }
    }
    close(MDSCAN);
    # no md devices found, but command output wasn't empty
    if($raid_count == 0 && $lines > 0) { _msg("MD status is UNKNOWN (can't get configuration info) - "); }
    elsif($raid_count == 0) { _msg("MD not configured on this system - "); }
    elsif($md_status eq "OK" && not defined $verbOutput) { _msg("MD Status is OK - ");  }  }
```

### mdadm --detail output

```
/dev/md0:
    Version : 0.90
Creation Time : Mon Mar  4 12:53:19 2013
 Raid Level : raid1
 Array Size : 521984 (509.84 MiB 534.51 MB)
Used Dev Size : 521984 (509.84 MiB 534.51 MB)
 Raid Devices : 2
Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 0
Persistence : Superblock is persistent

Update Time : Thu Jul  4 16:27:46 2013
      State : clean, degraded
Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
Failed Devices : 1
Spare Devices : 0

       UUID : 3a3bd078:31678889:9485a7cf:e1283d32
     Events : 0.438

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       0        0        0      removed
   1       8       33        1      active sync   /dev/sdc1

   2       8       17        -      faulty spare   /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: I might be confused here, but doesn't `removed` come first in the input?

Comment: Anyhow, I'd suggest either keying off `Failed Devices`, which probably mirrors the `faulty` state. or deferring the handling of `removed` until after you've processed the entire input.

Comment: This question is way too verbose. You need to trim away the excess and create a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Hasturkun Thank you mate for the answer. That is exactly what I want to do. Delay the evaluation of the `removed` state until the whole input has been parsed. Since I am a perl noob could you point me to the right direction?

Comment: @TLP I believe that my description is SSCCE compatible. It contains only the relevant information. I did not for example paste the whole perl script here. Just the relevant sub and the output of the command I am parsing so non-Linux wiz know what I am talking about. Thanks for the helpful link though.

Comment: @user2550665 Well, the thing is, you seem to be having a simple parsing issue, which normally would be solved in minutes. But here you are, 19 hours later, with no answer. With these kind of issues, what one needs is input, output and compilable code. If that is just the relevant code, then you have put a rather bad header above it, "Full script code".

Comment: I see you have fallen into the trap of using `||` with `open` without using parentheses. You should know that `||` has higher precedence than `,` (comma), so that `die` statement will never happen (because a non-empty string is always true). You should use the `or` operator instead.

Comment: Your intended logic is not clear. The first state in your file is 'removed' and that does not enter the if block because it hasn't found 'faulty' yet. The third state is 'faulty' and that sets $myfaulty to 1. What do you *want* to happen?

Comment: @Disco3 thank you for the answer. I just need to log the "removed" line only if the "faulty" is not there. If the faulty is there, like in the output above, I want only the faulty line to be logged.

Answer (score 1):

I made an attempt to look at your code, but it's rather painfully verbose, and does not fit on my computer screen, so I wanted to show you what you could do instead to parse that particular input.

First off, though, here's a trap for the unwary:

```
open MDDETAIL, "-|", "$MDADMCMD --detail $device" || die "can't run: $!";
```

If you look in [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity) you will notice in the precedence table that `||` has higher precedence than `,` (comma). What this means is that the statement above really means this:

```
open MDDETAIL, "-|", 
    ("$MDADMCMD --detail $device" || die "can't run: $!");
```

Or, in other words, the third argument for `open` becomes either a string, or a `die` statement. Since this string is not empty, it will always be true (it is a constant, after all), and since `||` short curcuits, the `die` statement can never happen. And even if it could, it is no longer associated with the `open` command's return value. Here's what you should do:

```
open(my $fh, "<", $file) || die $!;     # use parentheses to override precedence
open my $fh, "<", $file  or die $!;     # use "or" which has lower precedence
```

---

### Main question

Parsing your input is not difficult, just a bit finicky. Once it is parsed, you can extract the pieces you want with ease. So instead of writing *extremely* complicated loops and nested if-statements, just pick the text apart first.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %data;
my $input;
{
    local $/;                              # disable input record separator
    $input = <DATA>;                       # read entire input into one string
}
my ($num) = $input =~ /\n\n(Number.*)/s;   # extract table part
$input =~ s/\n\n(Number.*)//s;             # remove from keys/values
my @vals = grep /\S/, split /\n+/, $input;
my $dev = shift @vals;
$data{Device} = $dev;                      # extract dev name
for (@vals) {
    if (/^\s*([^:]+)\s*:(.*)/) {
        $data{$1} = $2;                # parse and store the key/values
    } else { warn "Bad data: $_"; }
}
my @nums = split /\n+/, $num;
my $header = shift @nums;                  # remove header
for (@nums) {
    s/^\s+//;                              # remove leading whitespace
    my @items = split /\s{2,}/;            # split on 2 or more whitespace
    my $state = $items[4];
    my $dev = $items[5] // "N/A";          # use fields as required
    print "Device: $dev, State: $state\n";
    # do stuff
}
print Dumper \%data;                       # this is the key/values we stored

# below is sample input
__DATA__
/dev/md0:
    Version : 0.90
Creation Time : Mon Mar  4 12:53:19 2013
 Raid Level : raid1
 Array Size : 521984 (509.84 MiB 534.51 MB)
Used Dev Size : 521984 (509.84 MiB 534.51 MB)
 Raid Devices : 2
Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 0
Persistence : Superblock is persistent

Update Time : Thu Jul  4 16:27:46 2013
      State : clean, degraded
Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
Failed Devices : 1
Spare Devices : 0

       UUID : 3a3bd078:31678889:9485a7cf:e1283d32
     Events : 0.438

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       0        0        0      removed
   1       8       33        1      active sync   /dev/sdc1
   2       8       17        -      faulty spare   /dev/sdb1
```

**Output:**

```
Device: N/A, State: removed
Device: /dev/sdc1, State: active sync
Device: /dev/sdb1, State: faulty spare
$VAR1 = {
          'Events ' => ' 0.438',
          'UUID ' => ' 3a3bd078:31678889:9485a7cf:e1283d32',
          'Persistence ' => ' Superblock is persistent',
          'Active Devices ' => ' 1',
          'Array Size ' => ' 521984 (509.84 MiB 534.51 MB)',
          'Spare Devices ' => ' 0',
          'Device' => '/dev/md0:',
          'State ' => ' clean, degraded',
          'Total Devices ' => ' 2',
          'Preferred Minor ' => ' 0',
          'Creation Time ' => ' Mon Mar  4 12:53:19 2013',
          'Used Dev Size ' => ' 521984 (509.84 MiB 534.51 MB)',
          'Failed Devices ' => ' 1',
          'Version ' => ' 0.90',
          'Raid Devices ' => ' 2',
          'Raid Level ' => ' raid1',
          'Working Devices ' => ' 1',
          'Update Time ' => ' Thu Jul  4 16:27:46 2013'
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are logging your output, as you parse each line BUT you need to know to about all lines in `mdadm --detail output` before you decide what to output.

You would need to refactor that bit of code which checks the $subdevice_status AFTER the file-parsing loop is over and so you can then check if you got removed AND $myfaulty is not true. You will need to store more information in variables, rather than log them straight out.